# angularfre2 FirebaseListObservable<any[]> push is not a function

Tags: angular

Trying to add new item in FirebaseListObservable array but it saying push is not a function

my array:

```
clients: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

Here is my form submit function:

```
onSubmit({value, valid}:{value:Client, valid:boolean}){
if(this.disableBalanceOnAdd){
  value.balance = 0;
}
if(!valid){
  this.router.navigate(['add-client']);
} else {
  // Add new client
  this.clientService.newClient(value);
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
}
```

here is my service:

```
constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.clients = this.af.list('/clients').valueChanges() as FirebaseListObservable<Client[]>;
}

newClient(client:Client){
this.clients.push(client);
// console.log(client);
}
```

don't find any solution. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: That's right, it's not. You don't have an array, you have *an observable of arrays*. Surely angularfire exposes a method to add a new item?

Comment: I was following a tutorial, this code is working for the tutorial but not mine.

Comment: You should double-check the tutorial and consider raising this with whoever made it, then, because the error is telling you that won't work.

Comment: Yes, I double checked the tutorial since 2-3 hours

Comment: What tutorial are you referring to? in https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md it's using `this.af.list('/clients')`, not `this.af.list('/clients').valueChanges()`

Comment: I need to add clientRef: AngularFireList<any> and then push to this clientRef. This works for me.